# Drupal javascript block does not display info window - same code in node does

Tags: javascript, google-maps, d3.js, drupal-7

I have a javascript google map which works correctly when the code is in a Drupal node. However, when I move the same code into a block it displays correctly but when the mouse hovers over an image overlaid on the map it displays an info popup in the node but not in the block. The pointer changes correctly when it hovers but nothing gets displayed.
The script includes d3.js code as an overlay on the google map. 
I would like to use a block to control the display in mobile devices.
Any suggestions as to the cause would be appreciated.

Comment: Ultimately this was solved by changing the display property to "inline" when the mouse hovered and then change it to "none" on mouseout. I have no idea why this worked in the node. (I had copied the code from another example script.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately this was solved by changing the display property to "inline" when the mouse hovered and then change it to "none" on mouseout. I have no idea why this worked in the node. (I had copied the code from another example script.)